# How can I dynamically add data to a list like this [Dart]

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I need some help. I just cannot figure out how to add data (here more animals with values) to a List like following:

```
List animal = [{ "display": "Dog", "value": "1",},{"display": "Cat","value": "2",}];
```

-> so the structure of a entry must be like **{"display" : "XYZ", "value": "NRXYZ"}**. Is there a function to dynamically add more animals with values.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use add() method:

```
animal.add({"display" : "XYZ", "value": "NRXYZ"});
```

If you want to add multiple animals at the end of the list you can use addAll() method:

```
animal.addAll([{ "display": "Ferret", "value": "3",}, {"display": "Bird", "value": "4",}]);
```

Comment: Thank‘s a lot! I‘ve already tried it this way but apparently i did something wrong. Howewer, now it‘s working! :-)